# How to optimize multiple calls to SQL when working with Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I have a situation where I am trying to import a table from SQL, concatenate it with another dataframe from pandas, and then return the concatenated dataframe back to SQL. However, I am doing this same process several times over.

For example, if I have a few dataframes such as

```
df1 = some data
df2 = other data
df3 = more data
etc.
```

For df1, I would then use PyODBC to create a query to SQL and save the table as a dataframe.

```
sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_to_database)
query = 'SELECT * FROM [Database].[Schema].[Table1]'
sql_data = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
```

At this point I would take `sql_data`, do what I need, then concatenate it with `df1` and spit it back to SQL using sqlalchemy

```
data = pd.concat([sql_data, df1)
data.to_sql('Table1', if_exists='replace')
```

All of this works fine, but my question comes when I have to replicate this process in a more elegant way. I can simply hardcode it by doing something like

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM [Database].[Schema].[Table2]'
sql_data = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
data = pd.concat([sql_data, df2)
data.to_sql('Table2', if_exists='replace')

query = 'SELECT * FROM [Database].[Schema].[Table3]'
sql_data = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
data = pd.concat([sql_data, df3)
data.to_sql('Table3', if_exists='replace')

etc..
```

However, this is obviously not the ideal solution. If I were to place this into a loop/function, I am most hung up on to how to set appropriate table names for each table and properly iterate through each dataframe so that it matches with the correct table from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you **only** append new information with each **dataframe** you have.

```py
dflist = [df1, df2, df3, ...]

# Collect all data we want to add
DataToAdd = pd.concat(dflist, axis=0, sort=False)

# sql_conn => the sqlalchemy connection object
# Send this data to sql
DataToAdd.to_sql('[Database].[Schema].[Table3]', con=sql_conn, if_exists='append')
```

Take a look at [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html?highlight=sql#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql) for any further customization.

Comment: The reason why i didn't use `if_exists='append` is so that if the program is accidentally run multiple times, it doesn't create unnecessary records. I didn't really include all of that in my example because I didn't think it was relevant to my particular question. The thing that I'm caught up on his how to best loop through each dataframe and SQL table so that `df1` concats with `Table1`, `df2` concats with `Table2`, etc

Answer (score 0):

For looping you can create a control table which holds the names of the tables you are interested in and then read those names in a list:

```
tables_list = etl.fromdb(landing_conn, "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM db.tables_list")
table_names = etl.values(tables_list, 'TABLE_NAME')
```

and then you can loop through the list:

```
    for item in table_names:
       df = do_something\concate\append()
```